# Returned to unanswered - Copying and pasting to a specific range of cells based on selection from drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range, paste

EDIT 2/10/18 - 22:45

I spoke too soon earlier and have updated my initial post. Whilst I thought that this problem had largely been solved, I have now seen that the objectives copy from `Objectives Entry Sheet` and are pasted in each section - Autumn, Spring and Summer - on the `Data Validation` sheet, regardless of where they are entered in the `Data Validation Sheet`.

For example if I enter text in F13 - the 'Autumn, Year 1, Objective 1' cell, pressing update copies the text to the Data Validation sheet into cells D19, J19 and P19 - the 'Year 1 Autumn, Spring and Summer Objective 1' cells

Please can anyone suggest what is causing this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubjectObjectives()
    Dim srcWs As Worksheet
    Dim trgWs As Worksheet
    Dim dvCell As Range
    Dim AutSrc As Range, SprSrc As Range, SumSrc As Range
    Dim Art As Range, Computing As Range, DT As Range, Geography As Range, History As Range, MFL As Range, Music As Range, PE As Range, RE As Range, Science As Range
    Dim AutTarget As Range, SprTarget As Range, SumTarget As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim hLink As Hyperlink

'Set source and target worksheets
    Set srcWs = Worksheets("Objectives Entry Sheet")
    Set trgWs = Worksheets("Data Validation")

'Set cell where Dropdown list is
    Set dvCell = Worksheets("Objectives Entry Sheet").Range("B11")

'Set where objectives are copied from
    Set AutSrc = srcWs.Range("F13:K18")
    Set SprSrc = srcWs.Range("F23:K28")
    Set SumSrc = srcWs.Range("F33:K38")

'Set where objectives are copied to

    If dvCell = "" Then GoTo Whoops

    If dvCell.Value = "Art" Then Set AutTarget = trgWs.Range("D19:U24")
    If dvCell.Value = "Art" Then Set SprTarget = trgWs.Range("J19:O24")
    If dvCell.Value = "Art" Then Set SumTarget = trgWs.Range("P19:U24")

    If dvCell.Value = "Computing" Then Set AutTarget = trgWs.Range("D25:U30")
    If dvCell.Value = "Computing" Then Set SprTarget = trgWs.Range("J25:O30")
    If dvCell.Value = "Computing" Then Set SumTarget = trgWs.Range("P25:U30")

    If dvCell.Value = "DT" Then Set AutTarget = trgWs.Range("D31:U36")
    If dvCell.Value = "DT" Then Set SprTarget = trgWs.Range("J31:O36")
    If dvCell.Value = "DT" Then Set SumTarget = trgWs.Range("P31:U36")

    If dvCell.Value = "Geography" Then Set AutTarget = trgWs.Range("D37:U42")
    If dvCell.Value = "Geography" Then Set SprTarget = trgWs.Range("J37:O42")
    If dvCell.Value = "Geography" Then Set SumTarget = trgWs.Range("P37:U42")

    If dvCell.Value = "History" Then Set AutTarget = trgWs.Range("D43:U48")
    If dvCell.Value = "History" Then Set SprTarget = trgWs.Range("J43:O48")
    If dvCell.Value = "History" Then Set SumTarget = trgWs.Range("P43:U48")

    If dvCell.Value = "MFL" Then Set AutTarget = trgWs.Range("D49:U54")
    If dvCell.Value = "MFL" Then Set SprTarget = trgWs.Range("J49:O54")
    If dvCell.Value = "MFL" Then Set SumTarget = trgWs.Range("P49:U54")

    If dvCell.Value = "Music" Then Set AutTarget = trgWs.Range("D55:U60")
    If dvCell.Value = "Music" Then Set SprTarget = trgWs.Range("J55:O60")
    If dvCell.Value = "Music" Then Set SumTarget = trgWs.Range("P55:U60")

    If dvCell.Value = "PE" Then Set AutTarget = trgWs.Range("D61:U66")
    If dvCell.Value = "PE" Then Set SprTarget = trgWs.Range("J61:O66")
    If dvCell.Value = "PE" Then Set SumTarget = trgWs.Range("P61:U66")

    If dvCell.Value = "RE" Then Set AutTarget = trgWs.Range("D67:U72")
    If dvCell.Value = "RE" Then Set SprTarget = trgWs.Range("J67:O72")
    If dvCell.Value = "RE" Then Set SumTarget = trgWs.Range("P67:U72")

    If dvCell.Value = "Science" Then Set AutTarget = trgWs.Range("D73:U78")
    If dvCell.Value = "Science" Then Set SprTarget = trgWs.Range("J73:O78")
    If dvCell.Value = "Science" Then Set SumTarget = trgWs.Range("P73:U78")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

       'Copy cell contents

            AutSrc.Copy
            AutTarget.PasteSpecial xlValues, skipblanks:=True
            AutSrc.ClearContents

            SprSrc.Copy
            SprTarget.PasteSpecial xlValues, skipblanks:=True
            SprSrc.ClearContents

            SumSrc.Copy
            SumTarget.PasteSpecial xlValues, skipblanks:=True
            SumSrc.ClearContents


    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

Whoops:
    MsgBox "Please select a subject from the dropdown menu and press 'Update' again."

End Sub
```

I wish users to be able to select the subject that they are entering objectives for from a drop down list on the **Objectives Entry Sheet**, enter the objectives into some or all of the cells in the Autumn, Spring and Summer Term sections, and then click the **Update** button to copy these objectives to the appropriate cell range (based on subject and term) on the **Data Validation Sheet**.

[image: Objectives Entry Sheet]

[image: Data Validation Sheet]

Also, is there a way to specify that any hyperlinks that are created in the Objective Entry Sheet are maintained when the cell contents are copied to the Data Validation Sheet as these cells will be used to populate other worksheets.

The file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LTuY9PFSlwiMyB0L-AJJOyRm2al5gSjc).

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the loop checking for empty cells and instead changed it to the "skipBlanks = true" under the pasteSpecial method. Works for me!

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubjectObjectives()
    Dim srcWs As Worksheet
    Dim trgWs As Worksheet
    Dim dvCell As Range
    Dim AutSrc As Range, SprSrc As Range, SumSrc As Range
    Dim Art As Range, Computing As Range, DT As Range, Geography As Range, History As Range, MFL As Range, Music As Range, PE As Range, RE As Range, Science As Range
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim cell As Range

'Set source and target worksheets
    Set srcWs = Worksheets("Objectives Entry Sheet")
    Set trgWs = Worksheets("Data Validation")

'Set cell where Dropdown list is
    Set dvCell = Worksheets("Objectives Entry Sheet").Range("B11")

'Set where objectives are copied from
    Set AutSrc = srcWs.Range("F13:K18")
    Set SprSrc = srcWs.Range("F23:K28")
    Set SumSrc = srcWs.Range("F33:K38")

'Set where objectives are copied to
    If dvCell.Value = "Art" Then Set Target = trgWs.Range("D19:I24")
    If dvCell.Value = "Computing" Then Set Target = trgWs.Range("D25:I30")
    If dvCell.Value = "DT" Then Set Target = trgWs.Range("D31:I36")
    If dvCell.Value = "Geography" Then Set Target = trgWs.Range("D37:I42")
    If dvCell.Value = "History" Then Set Target = trgWs.Range("D43:I48")
    If dvCell.Value = "MFL" Then Set Target = trgWs.Range("D49:I54")
    If dvCell.Value = "Music" Then Set Target = trgWs.Range("D55:I60")
    If dvCell.Value = "PE" Then Set Target = trgWs.Range("D61:I66")
    If dvCell.Value = "RE" Then Set Target = trgWs.Range("D67:I72")
    If dvCell.Value = "Science" Then Set Target = trgWs.Range("D73:I78")

'Begin loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      '  For Each cell In AutSrc

     '   If cell.Value <> "" Then

            AutSrc.Copy
            Target.PasteSpecial xlValues, skipBlanks:=True
      '  End If

       ' Next cell


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks oxwilder. I have gone with this answer as it is shorter and it matches my level of VBA understanding at the moment!

Comment: I've tried to add to the code to set the Spring and Summer targets but have hit a problem here, too! I don't suppose you have any advice for this do you?

Comment: @gbra Oh dang! What's the problem you're having? Is it that all your Target ranges are set to Aut and you haven't defined new ranges for Spr and Sum?

Comment: No, I had renamed all of the Target ranges correctly. I've managed to resolve the issue now by writing the `If dvCell...` line 3 times and setting a different target range in each one.

Comment: @gbra I saw your edit up there, and each one of those IF statements will resolve as true if the user selects "Art," so effectively the target will reset to Sum each time. You might need to do another drop down and select which term you'd like to edit.

Comment: @gbra Ok I think I got it (I missed your first edit): I think you'll want to execute a block of statements under each "then" instead of using "and." So `If dvCell.Value = "Art" Then Set AutTarget = trgWs.Range("D19:U24") Set SprTarget = trgWs.Range("J19:O24") set SumTarget = trgWs.Range("P19:U24")` --apologies, I can't do line breaks in the mini-comment, but there should be a new line at each `set`, then add `elseif` for each subject in the drop-down. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your for each loop does not work as intended.

What your code actually does is inserting the entire "Target" values into the autSrc range which should be opposite as i understand it.

Secondly it does insert the blank cells.

I'm no wizard but i would do something like this:

```
nRows = autSrc.rows.count

nCols = autSrc.columns.count

for i = 1 to nrows
    for k = 1 to nCols
        if autSrc.cells(i,k) <> "" then

            target.cells(i,k) = autSrc.cells(i,k)            

        end if
    next k
next i
```

Edit:
Further i would just point out that your code does not account for the different seasons as far as i can tell.

Comment: Thanks Mr ML. This makes sense - I thought that I could use something like this but couldn't visualise what it would like like and don't know enough VBA syntax yet to be able to compose it. For the time being, I have gone with the second response as it was shorter though! :)

Comment: Thinking about accounting for the different seasons, is it possible to set 3 target ranges from the single dropdown selection? I have edited my code but it isn't working in the way that I have done it - probably due to my misunderstanding of  how to use 'AND'.

Comment: Hi
No worries the other solution worked as well. I cannot find the problem with your new code. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If I enter text in, say, F13 - the 'Autumn, Year 1, Objective 1' cell, pressing update copies the text to the Data Validation sheet into cells D19, J19 and P19 - the 'Year 1 Autumn, Spring and Summer Objective 1' cells.

Comment: Your "autTarget" is set to range "D:U" which should be "D:I".
FYI you could use a case statement instead of all those IF's.

Comment: Hahaha - thank you Mr ML! I couldn't see the wood for the trees! I thought there would be a better way to write the if statements. I really need to get a book and learn properly rather than the ad hoc way that I have been doing on this project. Thanks so much for your help.